# Posting data that contains (percent sign %) in Axios is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

In NodeJS, I'm trying to send a post request to an API and I need to POST a password (which contains a % character) to the endpoint. Here is my code:

```
const reqData = {
    username: "myusername",
    password: "passwordincludes%sign"
}
const returnedToken = await axios.post(endpointUrl, reqData);
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

I've checked it and the problem is with the percent sign in password and some other special characters are fine but for example @ is not working either. if I send a password which doesn't contain "%" sign, it will work.

Any ideas how can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: maybe you can try to send this as a form-data instead of a raw json?
i am not sure but maybe form-data can handle this better

Comment: JSON.stringify(reqData) does not raise any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not related to your data! you did not catch the response properly.

```
const {data: returnedToken } = await axios.post(endpointUrl, reqData);
```

You are using the "response" that is very big and nested.

Comment: You're welcome. I was struggling with this problem a lot